Flask web application behaves incorrectly when deployed on Heroku with Gunicorn
I recently deployed a Flask web application on Heroku for the first time. The application works properly when running locally with app.py and also when using the built-in Flask server on Heroku.
However, I encountered an issue with the deployed version of the application when using Gunicorn. The problem arises when I attempt to perform certain actions, such as logging in. Instead of redirecting to the expected page (e.g., the dashboard), the application sometimes reloads the page without any redirection. This issue occurs intermittently, with approximately a quarter of attempts resulting in the correct redirection.
Additionally, even when I do manage to access the dashboard, the menu buttons sometimes redirect me back to the index page instead of the expected destinations. This behavior is also inconsistent and does not occur every time.
I've checked the Heroku logs (heroku logs --tail) but haven't found any errors or warnings that could explain the behavior.
Here's my Procfile configuration:
web: gunicorn -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT app:app

Any suggestions on how to diagnose and fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.


This issue occurs intermittently, with approximately a quarter of attempts resulting in the correct redirection.

You're running four workers (via the -w 4 argument to gunicorn), any of which could handle any request.
If you're seeing expected behaviour on roughly one out of four attempts, it's likely that you're doing something that works when the same worker serves the next request and fails if another one does. This may appear to work properly on your local machine if you're not running multiple workers there, which is common.
Since you mention logging in, it may be how you're doing sessions. Is that being done in-memory, e.g. via a global variable? That won't work properly. If you're using the local filesystem, that's also not a great idea. It may work across workers on the same dyno (though it also may not, I'm not sure) but it certainly won't work across multiple dynos.
A proper solution would be to fix whatever is being stored globally. If it's your SESSION_TYPE you can use another back-end. Something network-attached, like the SQLAlchemy or Redis back-ends, would be a good choice.
A non-solution that simply hides the problem at the expense of performance that I don't recommend would be to just run a single worker process instead of four.

I managed to solve this particular problem earlier by switching to redis session management. However, there was still worker related issues. When I updated data on the site and refreshed the page it would sometimes still load the old data. Currently I'm running it on 1 worker and I have no issues. Any idea how I could solve this and still have multiple workers?

@Lojas, it sounds like something isn't correctly abstracted away from the worker process (could be something in-memory, could be something on the filesystem if there's a per-worker directory... could be something else, I guess...) Are you using any global variables to manage state?

@Lojas, are you still having trouble with this?
